# atomicLong is it possible to do compareAndSet if atomic long larger than certain number?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I wish to compare the current `timestamp` in `AtomicLong` to `currentTimeMS` so that I know if some time has passed and if yes then only a single thread would enter a block of code but from what i see `compareAndSet` only compares to a specific value and its not possible to do `compareAndSet` if value is larger or smaller than another value.  is that possible?

```
if (myAtomicLong.compareAndSet(larger than last atomic long value + 10 seconds, 
System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 seconds)) {

// one thread enters here only as only one thread saw that current myAtomicLong 
// was larger than last timestamp recorded + 10 seconds.  
// and if yes immediately set the value to next 10 seconds.

// do some work

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are going for the wrong thing, a scheduled action is what you want here.

Comment: using a scheduler would mean having more complex objects in my code, my tests would become more difficult etc, here i just do a simple time comparison i find that a simpler design than using schedulers, moreover if i have a cache for example, then if there are no hits no need for scheduled invalidation, however if i do have hits i want to check when was last time of invalidation, in this way using this "if" I can be aware if i have requests for cache or not

Comment: I disagree with the "more complex" stuff -- _especially_ tests. On the opposite, given that a scheduler's tasks are all interfaces, you can mock them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ScheduledExecutorService` for this.

For a very simple reason: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not as reliable as you think... Its value will change if the OS time changes; whereas the implementations of `ScheduledExecutorService` use `System.nanoTime()`, which is a ticker running from the start of the JVM and which will always increase.

Note that `Timer` and `TimerTask` suffer the same problem!

Comment: for my specific use case i don't need reliable scheduler, i just want to know if 10 seconds passed if yes then i need to refresh some cache.  comparing last "db" read timestamp + 10 seconds, to current time sounds so simple to me that i wanted to use that instead of shcedulers which will become more complex, also in tests etc.

Comment: "i just want to know if 10 seconds passed" <-- `executor.schedule(yourStuff, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`